# Using gcloud for node.js how to share google cloud bucket images publicly

Tags: node.js, image, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

To store images in my Google Cloud Storage buckets, I use the [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcloud) npm module. Now my image is getting uploaded successfully. I want to share it publicly, but in the docs there is no parameter mentioned. Instead, I have to manually share all of my images publicly. Is there a way to share images publicly programmatically with google-cloud/storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below command and it made my bucket default publicly shared.

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://bucketname
```

Answer (score 1):

To mark an existing object as publicly readable, use this example [from the docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.1.1/storage/file?method=acl):

```
file.acl.add({
 entity: 'allUsers',
 role: gcs.acl.READER_ROLE
}, function(err, aclObject) {});
```

When doing an upload, either set the ACL like above, use a predefined ACL "publicRead", or just specify the option "public" when calling upload (see the [docs for the upload method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.1.1/storage/bucket?method=upload)).